# How to create d3js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am trying to learn d3js from http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

I am having csv file with following data

Category,Item,Day_of_week 
Yogurt,BlueBerries,2

Chips,Ruffles,5

Milk,Whole_Milk,3

Fruits,Apples,4

Nuts,Cashew,1

How do I make chart like this
[image]

Comment: The link you provided explains exactly how to do that. What trouble are you having with it exactly?

Comment: I want to read the values from file, but don't know how to ?

Comment: read the values from a file:http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/#data

Answer (score 1):

You can take Mike Bostock's code directly from the last snippet on [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/). You will have to change

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
```

to

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
```

(if your csv file is called data.csv). And you should delete the first column Category as you don't seem to be using it.

Since you want to write the food type on the bar and not the length you change

```
     .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

to

```
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBf9y/415/)